# How to integrate the logistic equation with partial fractions?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I’m trying to integrate the logistic equation, but I’m stuck with the partial fractions bit. None of the solutions I’ve found online (including here) clarify how it should go, and I keep getting something strange.

The form I‘ve arrived at after separating variables is:

$$\frac{dP}{P\left(1-\frac{P}{K}\right)}=r\,dt$$

And so I am trying to deal with the LHS of that:

$$\frac{dP}{P\left(1-\frac{P}{K}\right)} = \frac{A}{P} + \frac{B}{1-\frac{P}{K}}$$

The roots of $$-\frac{P^2}{K} + P = 0$$ are 0 and K.
Thus,

$$dP = A(1-\frac{P}{K}) + BP$$

When I plug in the roots, I get A = 0 and B = d (?!)

So I must have a mistake somewhere, but I can’t find it.
I’ll be grateful for any help!

UPD: Thank you for pointing out Mathjax to me. I’m sorry I didn’t format my solution properly before, I’m new here :)

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4000919/edit) your question to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), including what you keep getting, and also use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Rimdr, try this: what would you pick for $a$ and $b$ to make $aP^{-1} + b(1 - P/K)^{-1}$ add up to $P^{-1}(1 - P/K)^{-1}$? Common fraction, add, etc.